# Javascript table tr deletes on tr (Dynamic tr delete and re-generate tr id)

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table

I have a code which deletes a tr and regenerate tr's id sequence wise.
But It works on tr click and I want to do this on a button click. How I do this.

Here is my code

Here tr id is dynamic and a combination of alphabets and numbers

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $("tr").click(function() {

    $(this).nextAll().each(function() {

      var id = $(this).prop("id", function(index, idvalue) {
        console.log(idvalue);

        myArray = idvalue.split(/[0-9]+/);
        var id_text = myArray[0];
        console.log(id_text);

        var id_num = idvalue.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
        console.log(id_num);

        var new_no = id_num - 1;

        var new_id = id_text + '' + new_no;

        return new_id;

      });

    });

    $(this).remove();
  });

<
/script>
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='a1'>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td><input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="delete" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='a2'>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td><input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="delete" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='a3'>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td><input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="delete" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='a4'>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td><input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="delete" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='a5'>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td><input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="delete" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is - Ideally you shouldn't put the same id values of all the rows. id is for unique identifier in the entire DOM.

Next is - As you are doing with $(tr), it will take the entire row.

You can try something like:

```
        $("[name=btn]").click(function () {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        });
```

to remove the desired row on click of the button.

For rest of the manipulations, you can add your logic.

Comment: after applying [name=btn] this will not delete the whole row. It deletes only button.

Comment: if you are doing it with $(this).parents('tr').remove(); it will remove the entire row.